# Divide option in django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my model:

```
class DailyObj(models.Model):
          RedDate = models.DateField('RecDate')
          Name= models.CharField(Name,max_length=100,default=None)
          Total_Rec = models.DecimalField('Total Rec',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None) 



top10records = DailyObj.objects.filter(RedDate__gte =  fromdate,RedDate__lte = todate,Total_Rec__gt=0).order_by('-Total_Rec')[:10]
```

Here **fromdate** and **todate** are variables having proper date values.

The above query works fine and returns the records which satisfy the given criteria.

However I want each value of **Total_Rec** to be divided by 10,000,000 (i.e. I would like to convert whole amount in [crores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore)). Just to pass this modified values to template. I don't want to update actual table values.

Comment: You want the `Total_Rec` to be divided and written in db, or just to be presetned this way?

Comment: Just want present this way and pass it to template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a method like this:

```
class DailyObj(models.Model):
    ...
    def total_crores(self):
        return self.Total_Rec / 10000000
```

It won't be stored in the database, but will be accessible in the template with something like this:

```
{{ daily_obj.total_crores }}
```

Or, in keeping with your query, something like this (assuming that `top10records` gets added to the view's context):

```
<ul>
  {% for record in top10records %}
    <li>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ record.total_crores }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you would need to include the code above in the model class.

Comment: @Wtower Thanks. I made my answer more explicit.